# facebook ios publishing scores

Tags: ios, facebook-opengraph, publish, facebook-ios-sdk

i'm using facebook ios sdk 3.5, now following the instructions found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/open-graph/ and the code found in the FriendSmasher, i am trying to post a score. However, i'm not seeing any results on my feed.

Thanks

this is my test code for our game:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"100", @"score", nil];

NSLog(@"Posting new score of 100");

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu/scores", myFBID] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if(error){
            NSLog(@"AN ERROR HAS OCCURED: %@", error.debugDescription);
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Score posted");
    }];
```

the request permissions is done using the deprecated function openActiveSessionWithPermissions with email and publish_actions passed

Comment: deprecated means no longer supported, you shouldn't use these functions as they won't work as expected in the future (or now)

Comment: thanks, but i've tried also the non-deprecated functions, first is the openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions and openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions, but it is still not posting

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Activity Log on the desktop for score stories. You'll see stories if you get a high score for example, so you can test that. The fact that a score was posted does not show up in News Feed. The stories that may show up when a score is posted are stories like passing stories (you passed a friend) or high score stories. You can always check these types of stories in your Activity Log.